# Line from file isn't reading after using pointer inside the loop

Tags: c, file

So I am trying to read a matrix from a file (I am sure there are better ways to do it than how I am doing it). I had a hard time figuring out how to read each word from the file (meaning each entry of the matrix) so decided to read each line and use something I found here in stackexchange called `strtok`.

The inside of my `main()` looks like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    FILE *f;
    int nmatrix=3;
    int nmax=3;
    int something;
    int number, count, count2, i, j;
    srand(time(NULL));
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    char * line = NULL;
    char * pch;
    int ia;
    int (*B)[nmatrix][nmatrix] = malloc(nmatrix * nmatrix * sizeof(int));


    while(nmatrix<=nmax){
        // Creation of Matrix
        f = fopen("matrix.txt", "w");
        for(count = 1; count <= nmatrix; count ++){
            for(count2 = 1; count2 <= nmatrix; count2 ++){
                number = rand()%9;
                fprintf(f, "%s%d ", " ", number);
            }
            fprintf(f, "%s\n", " ");
        }
        fclose(f);

        // Reading Matrix
        f = fopen("matrix.txt", "r");
        i=0;
        while((read = getline(&line, &len, f)) != -1) {
            printf("%s\n", line);
            pch = strtok(line," ,.-");
            j=0;
            while (pch != NULL & j<nmatrix){
                ia= (int)*pch-48;
                *B[i][j]= ia;
                pch = strtok(NULL, " ,.-");
                j=j+1;
            }
            i=i+1;
        }
        fclose(f);

        nmatrix=nmatrix+1;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The first output in terminal is if the line  `*B[i][j]= ia;` is erased, and the second with it. The first ouput reads all the lines in the file and the second doesnt read the last. Why? (The output looks different cuz the matrices are generated at random).

Thanks in advance
[image]

I am fairly new to everything, specially pointers so if anything is not used correctly I'd appreciate the comment.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. While I'm, happy to see a beginner using the correct type for a matrix: a 2D array, you could make your life easier if you used a pointer to a 1D array, though. I sometime answered such questions already, you might want to check my profile::answers.

Comment: You did not allocate `memory` for `line` that's why program is crashing, first allocate memory to store the `string` in `line`.

Comment: Ok I put the whole code now, at least now if anyone wants to run it they wont have to create a file (the code creates it).

Comment: @krpra, why do you say it's crashing if there is no error? And not sure what you are saying with I first have to allocate memory to store the string, can you be more specific please.

Comment: your code has `char * line=NULL` when you are passing `line` in `getline()` it is still pointing to `NULL`,when `getline()` copies the string in `line` it does not find any space for storing, either you call `malloc` to allocate memory or declare `array` of `char` of reasonable length

Comment: @krpra No. Please [RTF `getline()` M](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html)  *If `*lineptr` is a null pointer or if the object pointed to by `*lineptr` is of insufficient size, an object shall be allocated as if by `malloc()` or the object shall be reallocated as if by `realloc()`, respectively, such that the object is large enough to hold the characters to be written to it*

Answer (score 0):

You had a couple of issues.  You were using & instead of && (not really affecting it, but still wrong) and you had your pointer wrong in the assignment. I changed the output to display what is stored in the matrix, instead of the read line.
       `*B[i][j]= ia;` needs to be `(*B)[i][j]= ia;`

```
   // Reading Matrix
    f = fopen("matrix.txt", "r");
    i=0;
    while((read = getline(&line, &len, f)) != -1) {
        pch = strtok(line," ,.-");
        j=0;
        while (pch != NULL && j<nmatrix){
            printf("\n%d %d :", i, j);
            ia= (int)*pch-48;
            (*B)[i][j]= ia;
            printf("%d\n", (*B)[i][j]);
            pch = strtok(NULL," ,.-");
            j=j+1;
        }
        i=i+1;
    }
    fclose(f);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have a lot of errors:

- your string to break the numbers os the matrix are not inserted when you create the matrix: " ,.-". These must be inserted to be used in strtok function.
- should be && instead of & in while statement
- you have an extra } at the end of file.
- both whiles to create the matrix should start at 0 and go to nmatrix with < symbol.
- you should initialize the string line with "", not null.

  int main(){

  ```
  FILE *f;
  int nmatrix=3;
  int nmax=3;
  int number, count, count2, i, j;
  srand(time(NULL));
  size_t len = 0;
  ssize_t read;
  char * line = "";
  char * pch;
  int ia;
  int (*B)[nmatrix][nmatrix] = malloc(nmatrix * nmatrix * sizeof(int));
  while(nmatrix<=nmax){
      // Creation of Matrix
      f = fopen("matrix.txt", "w");
      for(count = 0; count < nmatrix; count ++){
          for(count2 = 0; count2 < nmatrix; count2 ++){
              number = rand()%9;
              fprintf(f, "%s%d ", " ", number);
          }
          fprintf(f, "%s\n", " ");
      }
      fclose(f);

      // Reading Matrix
      f = fopen("matrix.txt", "r");
      i=0;
      while((read = getline(&line, &len, f)) != -1) {
          printf("%s\n", line);
          pch = strtok(line," ");
          j=0;
          while (pch != NULL && j < nmatrix){
              ia= (int)*pch-48;
              *B[i][j]= ia;
              pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
              j=j+1;
          }
          i=i+1;
      }
      fclose(f);

      nmatrix=nmatrix+1;
  }
  return 0;
  ```

  }

Comment: Thanks! The space is how they are separated and it is in " ,.-". Someone else had answered saying that allocating the string should fix it and proposed initializing the string as `char * line= (char *)malloc( 100 * sizeof(char));` which I did and nothing changed.

Comment: *you should initialize the string line with "", not null.* Not correct.  The use of `line`, `len`, and `getline()` in the posted code is correct. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html  The name of the variable used to store the result - `read` - could be better as it conflicts with the POSIX `read()` function, but that's not incorrect, either, even if it might be confusing in some ways.

Comment: If the space is what you use as a separator, you have to use " " in strtok function, not " ,.-". I tested here and worked just fine.